# .NET Framework 4 KB2162169 documentation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Does anyone knows what newly released ".NET Framework 4 KB2162169" contain? Any links would be helpful.

(Also, does anyone knows if this update is available through Windows Update?)

Thanks.
Datte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize if this is not what you are looking for.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2162169

Were you looking for something different?  Again, my apologies if this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Hi Terry, I appreciate your quick reply. The link you have sent is about VS2010SP1 Beta release, it does not say anything about what .NET Framework 4 Update contains.

Answer (score 1):

It's [.Net 4.0 SP1 beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/productfeedback/archive/2010/12/07/going-live-with-the-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta.aspx).

Comment: Hi SLaks, I had seen the Microsoft KB link you posted. At the bottom of the page, they have a list of issue thats been fixed. Is it just a bugfix update? or do they have something more than that?